# How to use SQL function output in a cte in Serverless SQL?

Tags: t-sql, serverless, azure-synapse

I have a function which outputs a table, called fnDimDate(startDate, endDate).

I need to use this table in further data transformations. I created a CTE like this:

```
WITH CTE_get_dates_between_first_and_last
AS (
    SELECT [Date]
    FROM [dbo].[fnDimDate](@FirstDate, @LastDate)
)
```

If I then try to join those dates coming from that table on other data, like this:

```
,CTE_join_together
AS(
    SELECT data.Title,
           dates.[Date]
    FROM [some].[ServerlessView] AS data
    LEFT JOIN CTE_get_dates_between_first_and_last AS dates 
    ON dates.[Date] >= sustainability.DateFrom AND dates.[Date] <= sustainability.DateTo
)
```

I get the following error:

> The query references an object that is not supported in distributed
> processing mode.

How can I use the output of the function in further data transformations in Synapse Serverless T-SQL, without having to save the output physically?

Comment: `SELECT data.Title, dates.[Date]   FROM [some].[data] AS data` -- **Is [some].[data] table an external table?**

Comment: No it is a view. I have named it differently to add more clarity

Comment: Date dimension tables are supposed to be *tables* - instead of having to calculate dates , months, quarters and their labels on the fly without indexing, you use a precalculated, heavily-index table with eg 20 years worth of dates and any other reporting column you may need. Such a table won't be big and makes a perfect candidate for columnstore indexes or compression

Comment: As for the error itself it complains that an unsupported object or function was used. What do `fnDimDate` and `ServerlessView` contain? Can you call each one separately? I suspect one of them contains an unsupported function

Comment: Yes I can call them seperately and they return what I expect, it only gives the error when I try to join them as shown in the question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes but we are using serverless sql, so we do not have tables. We save the final output as csv's. I was thinking of reading in the csv of the DimDate but I wanted to see whether there was a different solution to it.

Comment: @Jem no tables means no data. You *do* have tables somewhere, even if they're virtual (eg a view over a CSV file). You still haven't posted the code of the failing function or view, so we can't help

Comment: If you google for `Azure Synapse Date Dimension` you'll find articles and even SO questions that fill and return temporary tables, or store the generated dates in a Blob storage CSV. Did you try to use sys.objects or something similar to generate a tally table?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The fnDimDate uses sys.all_objects to get a date I think? Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @StartDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a. It then cross join with all dates between the firstDate and lastDate to get all the columns for that date, such as year, quarter, month, etc etc. We do also save this output to the data lake in a csv format. But I wanted to generate this table on the fly for only the period I would need instead of using the csv file.

Comment: have you tried using a WHILE loop instead?